# Don't understand the normal force in this picture

Tags: forces

The picture shows 2 beads threaded on a circular wire and attached together by a string. My intuition says the normal force should be an outwards force as the weight pulls the beads towards the centre. It looks to me like the forces are unbalanced in the radial direction which I was under the assumption can't be true if the beads are at rest.

Can anyone explain what's happening please?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are the beads spinning?

Comment: It doesn't specify, so I assume the beads are at rest.

Comment: Yeah, in that case your reasoning is sound, I think. The diagram appears to be wrong.

Comment: I suppose the two normal forces should exhibit opposite directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong. The normal vector, by definition, must assure the point doesn't leave the curve. This configuration would make the beads leave the curve towards the center.

Answer (score 2):

If the contact force direction is per the diagram then the magnitude has to be negative for the forces to balanace. You are correct in seeing that the diagram is badly drawn for this case.

Comment: Maybe this is a better way to put it than simply saying the diagram is wrong.

Comment: @probably_someone No. Understanding that sometimes you have to assign the 'direction' of a force in the absence of knowledge of it's "actual" direction and that this is OK because solving the system will simply give you a negative value for that force is a big step in being able to handle simple mechanics. I deliberate give students questions in which they can't know the the direction of a frictional force *a priori* and make them go through the exercise for exactly that reason. Some direction normal to the wire must be assigned. Which direction doesn't actually matter.

Comment: @probably_someone. The diagram may follow the convention that a positive normal direction is towards the center of curvature always. This is common in differential geometry. But if the normal vector is such, the magnitude has to be negative for the forces to balance.